# How do I update an entry while using @detail_route?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I update a model when using @detail_route?

See code below which is working for `POST` but not for `PATCH`. If I send in a `PATCH` request it creates a new entry i.e. it posts.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3)


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'type')


class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    filter_fields = ('id', 'type',)

    def get_serializer_class(self, data=None, request=None):

        return CompanySerializer(data=data, context={'request': self.request}, partial=True)

    @detail_route(methods=['post', 'patch'], url_path='private') 
    def private_company(self, request, version, pk=None):
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class(request.data, self.request)
        serializer.is_valid(request)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)   # <<== What do I need to do an update?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `private_company()` as below

```
@detail_route(methods=['post', 'patch'], url_path='private')
def private_company(self, request, version, pk=None):
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(data={"status": "updated", "data": serializer.data})
    else:
        do
        something else with POST request if needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have the link where this is detailed out on DRF/Django docs?

Comment: One more thing which now looks like a second question. In the serializer being fetched above, I have a custom `def validate(self, data):` function. Now I notice that during a `PATCH` that validate function is not being called. Do I need to define something else to allow custom validation during `PATCH`?

Comment: A weird thing with `@detail_route(methods=['post', 'patch'], url_path='private')`. I notice that the second method in that list responds with Method not allowed. I.e. if `PATCH` is the second element, I get method not allowed. If I move `POST` to be the second element in the `methods` list I also get Method `POST` not allowed `HTTP 405`.

Comment: I think here you can find the [`detail_route()` decoretor doc`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Comment: Usually the `validate()` being called during  the `is_valid()` calling. I will try to reproduce the behavior and will give you an update ASAP

Comment: @lukik I tried to reproduce the error.But failed. I couldn't reproduce the two problems you mentioned in comments( custom validation error and multiple methods problem). Better you ask a new question in SO community